# Iterate value from an array of objects with dynamic key, value and show inside a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I had created an arry of objects in localStorage. Inside the object, I am taking the input from a FORM and putting the form-label and the form-input as a key and value pair respectively inside the object and then setting it to the localStorage in the form of an array. The length of the object could be any (not static) and keys and values are also dynamic as you can see in the image, [Array Image from LocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngecj.png), some objects contain only 4 key and value and some are containing 5 or 6 pairs and can contain many more.

I am wanting to print every object in the form of a card and display it, so that the user can see the submitted forms.

But what is happening is that, instead of getting a card, I am getting the output in this manner.[Form value output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikak.png). Every key is printed separately. Please provide a solution or correct me by providing a different approach.

Here is the code :

FORMLIST COMPONENT :

```
function FormList() {

    const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('output'));

    const localityParameterSets = arr.map(function (value) {
        return Object.entries(value).map(([key, val]) => {
            return {
                name: key,
                value: val
            };
        });
    });

    return (
        <div className='form_list_main'>
            {
                localityParameterSets.map((element, index) =>
                    <FormListCard key={index} arrayOfElement={element} />
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default FormList;
```

FORMLISTCARD COMPONENT :

```
function FormListCard({ arrayOfElement }) {

    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setArray(arrayOfElement);
    }, []);

    return (
        array.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index} className='form_list_card'>
                    <div>
                        <h6>{item.name}</h6>
                        <p>{item.value}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    );
}

export default FormListCard;
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try to nest the `array.map` in the `FormListCard` component:

```
function FormListCard({ arrayOfElement }) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArray(arrayOfElement);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div key={index} className='form_list_card'>
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h6>{item.name}</h6>
            <p>{item.value}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormListCard;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to my question. IT WORKED as I wanted. 